# Mobile web page.. Part of page hidden behind smartphone controls

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a web page and that works like a app..
everything works ok, but some parts of page are hidding itself behind the smartphone controls (android devices only i guess)
in css is defined

```
html, body{
width:100%;
height:100%;

margin:0px;

position:fixed;

overflow:scroll;
}
```

in html on meta we have

```
<meta name='viewport' http-equiv="Content-Type" content="user-scalable=0; text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

the problem is be cause some components are fixed and a part of boddy rolls over this components.. than i need body with the exactly size of viewport

can someone help?

Comment: a screenshot would be helpful...

Comment: Why are you using `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `initial-scale=1`? in your `<meta>` tag?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

as this [w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) says:

> A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
>
> The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.